# How to initialize a container struct without knowing its size?

Tags: c++, numeric, scientific-computing

I am an amateur in C++, I am working on an scientific computing code. I defined a struct to store all the data input from the file. In the struct I have several 2D and 1D arrays whose dimensions depend on the data input, so I need to dynamically define the struct according to the data input. How can I achieve this goal in C++? Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Use `std::vector`s in the `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this depending on how you are parsing the input deck. The simplest way to do this would be through [std::vectors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which are a part of the Standard Template Library. These use dynamic memory and will be allocated on the heap. You can do something like the following:

```
// simple prototype of your struct
struct input_data{
  std::vector<double> one_d_data;
  std::vector<std::vector<double>> two_d_data;
};

// ad-hoc example of parsing and adding data to the 1d data container
while(still_parsing){
  double value = parser.get_next_1d_value();
  input_data.one_d_data.push_back(value);
}
```

The 2d case really depends on how much you know about the data. If you know all entries are a standard 3 component vector or 9 component tensor then you can pre-allocate those.

Either way it sounds like you should do some reading about `std::vector` and determine the best path forward for your design.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's extremely helpful to my programming! Thanks again!